# AWS CDK, creating an alias record for an existing hosted zone in Route53

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

I am using the AWS CDK (with Python as my deployment language) and I am trying to add an alias record of an existing cloudfront distribution to an existing hosted zone. While I can get `cdk synth` to work, `cdk deploy` fails not finding the hosted zone.

I tested with AWS CDK version 1.5.0 (build c020efa) and 1.6.0 (build 3a0cde0).

I tried finding the zone like so:

```py
zone = route53.HostedZone.from_hosted_zone_attributes(
    self,
    'MyHostedZone',
    zone_name = props.domainName,
    hosted_zone_id = 'Z1XXXXXXXXXS1'
)
```

And like so:

```py
zone = route53.HostedZone.from_lookup(
    self,
    'MyHostedZone',
    domain_name = props.domainName
)
```

And using it with (which works if a new hosted zone is created):

```py
route53.ARecord(
    self,
    'SiteAliasRecord',
    record_name = siteDomain,
    target = route53.RecordTarget(alias_target=target),
    zone = zone
)
```

In both cases, the error message is:

> StaticSiteHTTPS/SiteAliasRecord
>   (StaticSiteHTTPSSiteAliasRecord9BXXXXX) No hosted zone found with ID:
>   Z2XXX6BQ9TEB5H (Service: AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 404; Error Code:
>   NoSuchHostedZone; Request ID:

I do not know where ID `Z2XXX6BQ9TEB5H` comes from it is not in my template and I do not have a hosted zone with this ID.
Both generate a .template.json that contains:

```
"StaticSiteHTTPSSiteAliasRecord9BXXXXX": {
  "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
  "Properties": {
    "Name": "dev.mydomain.com.",
    "Type": "A",
    "AliasTarget": {
      "DNSName": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "StaticSiteHTTPSSiteDistributionCFDistribution3BXXXXX",
          "DomainName"
        ]
      },
      "HostedZoneId": "Z2YYYYYYYYYW2"
    },
    "HostedZoneId": "Z1XXXXXXXXXXS1"
  },
```

`from_lookup` generates `"HostedZoneId": "/hostedzone/Z1XXXXXXXXXXS1"`, while `from_hosted_zone_attributes` generates `"HostedZoneId": "Z1XXXXXXXXXXS1"` in template.json but either way `deploy` does not find the hosted zone. However, this seems to suggest that `synth` finds the hosted zone OK, running `cdk context` entries are created there by `synth`, too.

I also tried getting the hosted zone via `from_hosted_zone_id` and `from_hosted_zone_attributes` which also throw errors, but my understanding is that they do not actually look anything up in my account.

On a side note, creating a new hosted zone with the CDK works and it contains the alias record.

How can I debug this further? Should I be using a different mechanism to provide or lookup my hosted zone?

Comment: I'm not sure in python, but in TS it works by just having this:
`const zone = PublicHostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, `${stackName}-hosted-zone`, {
            hostedZoneId: staticSiteArgs.HostedZoneId,
            zoneName: staticSiteArgs.HostedZoneName
        });`

**Then create the record:**

`new routing.ARecord(this, `${stackName}-dns-record`, {
            zone: zone,
            recordName: fullDnsRecordName,
            target: routing.AddressRecordTarget.fromAlias(target),
            ttl: cdk.Duration.minutes(staticSiteArgs.DnsTTLMinutes)
        });`

Comment: @charlybones, many thanks for confirming your working ts code. I believe my Python code is almost identical. Following your example, I now also tried with PublicHostedZone rather than HostedZone. Unfortunately, I get the same error message. Maybe I raise an issue in the CDK github.

Answer (score 14):

Apologies for not having this in Python, but I have gotten a Route53 alias to work for a CloudFront distribution before.

I would try creating your alias record target by, first, importing the Route53 targets module:

```
...
import route53 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-route53');
import targets = require('@aws-cdk/aws-route53-targets');
```

Then when you've instantiated your distribution, you can create the alias record target with:

```
const hostedZoneId; // get from props or SSM lookup (Z****)
const zoneName; // get from props or SSM lookup (mydomain.com)
const myHostedZone = route53.HostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, 'MyImportedHostedZone', {
  hostedZoneId,
  zoneName,
});

aliasRecord = new route53.ARecord(this, 'MyAliasRecord', {
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.CloudFrontTarget(distribution)),
  zone: myHostedZone,
  recordName: 'SiteAliasRecord',
};
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for sharing. I had tried the corresponding Python code in the past, too. The problem was if I passed something as zone that was not created as part of the stack, but existed already, the lookup would fail during deployment and I had no way of updating the existing zone. How are you getting/setting myHostedZone in your example?

Comment: Hey @ikkjo, I'm importing the hosted zone from the same AWS account I'm deploying to, via a CDK import, similar to what you've described. The above response has been edited to include the hosted zone import code. I originally implemented this on CDK 1.8.0, and it appears to still work as of 1.18.0. If your CDK version is relatively up to date, and you're sure that the zone ID and name values are correct, perhaps there is some kind of python specific issue.

Comment: Hi @john-shaskin, many thanks for confirming! I also tried with 1.16.0 and had the same problems. I guess you are right and it might be a language specific problem. For reference, I opened https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3913 and it seems that the CDK folks agree since this has been triaged from guidance to bug.

Answer (score 1):

This might not exactly solve your problem, but `from_hosted_zone_id` seems to work ok in python.

```
zone = route53.HostedZone.from_hosted_zone_id(self, "existing-zone", 
       hosted_zone_id = MyHostedZoneId)


record = route53.ARecord(self, 'AliasRecord',
            record_name = MyRecordName,
            target = route53.RecordTarget(alias_target = target), zone = zone)
```

worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! Will try that again. As I said in the question, I did try at the time and it did not work, maybe sufficient time has passed and some bug fixes make this work now. good to know it can work at least.

Comment: what is `target` here? `alias_target=target`... a string?